# How can I repair or remove my bathroom sink's tailpiece?

Tags: plumbing, drain, tools, sink

I easily removed the S bend pipes, but the "last piece" actually in the sink is leaky.

(I do not know what that piece is called.)

[image]

Notice I've got it a bit loose .. close up ..

[image]

close up underneath ...

[image]

1. is there a special **tool** for this maybe?
2. notice the last large image - that large plastic turnable collar/bolt - in fact, is my problem just that I have to **turn that**? It's very hard to turn more, unclear if it can turn more. (If so I will get more purchase on it and do so, but maybe that's not the issue?)
3. last image - notice the black flange-thing against the white sink, has a **kind of notch** to our left - is that relevant to my problem ?!
4. notice the unit has the "stopper inside the drain".  I hate those, so, I will ideally replace it with just an ordinary plain one, no stopper mechanism. (So, up top the silver pull handle behind the taps will just do nothing.) Is that OK, no pitfalls?
5. If it works out, do you use a sealant?? or such putting the new piece in?
6. Finally - I know every detail of how to, say, plaster a wall. But I always get a plasterer to plaster a wall! Is this one of those things where you really need someone who has done it 1000 times, to end up with a perfect seal?  (The whole point here is it has a drip I can't beat.) Should I just get a plumber?

Maybe I have H.U.A. and the drip is not related to this, I mean, perhaps replacing this piece is misguided in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you just continue unscrewing the large black retaining ring counter-clockwise.  Previous person may have tighten it with a wrench (channel lock pliers). You have to unscrewed it a few turns.  Once loosen, the tailpipe will come off.
2. Use a wrench and remove the flat nut on bottom of the sink.  Once nut is completely removed, the drain pipe can be removed from the top.  
   [image]

Comment: thank you so much - great answer - maybe I am simply not getting enough purchase on the large black ring?  to be clear if I hold the TAILPIPE (YELLOW ARROW) firmly, say with rubber gloves, should the large black ring then turn if I am strong enough?  or is the tailpipe irrelevant to turning the large black ring ?!  heh!

Comment: The large black ring holds the tailpipe (yellow arrow) via pressure on a lip at the end of the tailpipe,  Tailpipe is irrelevant to turning the large black ring.  Yes, a pair of gloves would help in gripping the black retainer ring.  Try and get two hands on it.  I was going to suggest the glove first, but since you were having difficulty, I assume the previous person used a wrench and really tighten it down.

Answer (score 1):

The typical setup here is you have

1. The top collar
2. A rubber gasket or sealant (i.e. plumber's putty or silicone)
3. The sink holes
4. A rubber gasket
5. A compression collar

The rubber gasket can be a fiddly thing, where you need to seat and re-seat it to get a positive seal. If you're having trouble with it (and based on the pictures I'd say that's likely) try coating it in petroleum jelly. It should help if you have any odd spots in the sink hole that the rubber can't fill

Comment: ah I've got it - awesome answer thanks. You know, I wonder if I can ever really get a perfect seal - unless I've done it 100 times. maybe better just to get a plumber to save time  :/

Answer (score 0):

It's called a tail piece and usually comes with the faucet.  The piece in back of it with the rod connected controls your stopper (which I don't see, has it gone missing?).  It could be leaking around the drain fitting in the sink.  There is usually a rubber gasket that seals it but it may have gone bad. The black nut with the ridges on  it should turn separately from the tail piece allowing you to remove it if you wanted. There may be a gasket there too that needs replacing.

All this comes with the caveat that I usually do electrical work, not plumbing!  Maybe others could improve on this answer.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer George!  **The black nut with the ridges on it** .. do you mean, the large black plastic "nut" say two inches tall which has about 8 ridges on it? or do you mean the low flat thing (almost like a thick washer) pressed against the sink, up top in that photo??

Comment: When installing, the silver ring in the basin is threaded into the tailpiece,  then the black nut tightens the black rubber washer up to make a seal. reverse to uninstall. It appears someone has added silicone, this is usual not needed so it may have been a failed fix.

Comment: Yes - you just unscrew the large black retaining ring,  You have unscrewed it several turns, you need to continue unscrewing it.  It may be hard because the threads has junk in them.  Try retighten it a little, wipe/clean the lower threads and unscrew the nut again.

Comment: @Programmer66 The black nut only loosens the pipe from the sink, it can not be removed by unscrewing, They still need to unscrew the chrome drain bezel before the tail piece can be pulled down and out.